# How to remove focus from an Apps Script image button (Google Sheets)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a couple of buttons automating workflow on a Google Sheet.

After the assigned script has run, the image/button keeps keyboard focus. It only loses focus by pressing the escape key.

I haven't been able to find a **programatic way to remove focus** so I can get busy on the keyboard right away. There is one 'workaround' on here that opens then closes a sidebar but this is anything but elegant AND requires unncessary user permissions.

Any ideas?

[edited to add: .activate() and .setActiveSelection(range) do NOT remove focus from the image]

Comment: There is no way to manage focus or other client-side functionality in Google Apps Script (that I know of)

Comment: @DmitryKostyuk .activate

Comment: Of course, well done! @RemcoE33

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is: There is currently no functionality to do this as of September 2021.

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question...

Comment: [*Should I delete my answer if the answer is "No, this is not possible"?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344323/1364007) - tl;dr: "No" is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

[.activate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#setactivesheetsheet) will fit your needs.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
sheet.getRange('A1').activate;

//Or this to go to the first empty cell in col A

var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1).activate;
```

Comment: Don't forget the brackets after `activate()` :)

Comment: Unfortunately .activate() doesn't work. Neither does .setActiveSelection(range). They both change the active cell but the image still has focus and requires an esc press to move focus to the cell.